# SQL command is doubling up

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a project I made a table, but when I went to do: `SELECT * FROM TableName` I have been getting 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105.  I only want it to do 101 - 105.

```
Create TABLE Cust (Customer_Number CHAR(3), address VARCHAR(20), balance SMALLMONEY

INSERT INTO Cust (Customer_number, balance, address)
    VALUES (101, 200, null), (102, 700, null), (103, 1000, null), (104, 1500, null), (105, 2000, null)

SELECT *
FROM Cust
```

That is what I have and as I said I keep getting 10 slots instead of 5.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, every time I have done the `SELECT * FROM ()` command I have always got it to double or triple up?  Any help will help also thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try going to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and create your example there and see if the same happens. If it does - then you can post a link here and we can look at it, if it doesn't - then you've eliminated your sql as the cause for your "doubling" and that it is likely something else in some code in the sql server.
Also check you don't have any triggers on the table

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  Maybe you ran the INSERT statement multiple times after you created the table?

Comment: Refer this Fiddle - [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d8c26/1][1] . I think the insertion is done twice.

To avoid such scenarios its better to have primary key on table.

Answer (score 0):

You have done insertion on table multiple times . First empty all the data and then do the INSERT

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Cust
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing the INSERT INTO Execute, then SELECT FROM Execute

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine.see here

## [SQl fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/922738/1)

Answer (score 0):

Some times when we are in hurry and end up doing some thing wrong unknowingly. So please use

```
Truncate Table Table_name
```

to truncate the table and then re-insert the rows. Also  keep in mind that char and varchar data needs to be within single quotes.